# Pass data on segue after loading from remote

Tags: ios, swift, segue, viewcontroller

I have controller with this code:

```
var adItem: JSON!
var item: JSON? {
    didSet {
        self.loadAdData()
    }
}

func loadAdData() {
    let url = "\(Config.apiAdsUrl)\(item!)/"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
        if (json != nil) {
            var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
            self.adItem = jsonObj
        }
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "imagesSegue" {
        let infoIC = segue.destinationViewController as AdImagesViewController
        infoIC.adItem = self.adItem // this line pass nil value to controller, but i need to pass that JSON data
    }
}
```

I wanna fetch data and pass it to segue view controller.

I can't get that adItem in AdImagesViewController, when i print it, i always get nil, becouse prepareForSegue fires on start, so loadAdData needs some time to get data from remote..

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: `What do you mean by "segue fires on start"? What is triggering the segue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If would you like to segue regardless of when you have data, you could have a separate, singleton object handle the fetch.  This controller and the controller you segue to could both have access to the object.  Whenever the JSON changes, the object could notify the controller to refresh with the new data.

You could also wait until the data has been fetched to call performSegue, but what if the user has low service or no service at all?  But if this is what you want, you could create a shouldSegue Boolean variable and set it to YES.  In the callback, check if the flag is set to YES and if so perform the segue. You could use queues, too. The segue is UI related and occurs on the main queue, while the fetch usually is placed on a background queue and then updates the UI.  Maybe place the fetch on the main queue? :-/

Comment: can you give me example for some solutions, what you think is best?

Comment: how to notify controller to refresh?

Comment: When you want your model to notify the controller that the data has been updated, you typically use NSNotification (http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/) or Key-Value Observing (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).  For NSNotification, post a notification when new data is available, and just make sure that refresh in the controller is called when the notification is received.  It's similar for KVO, but you execute the refresh when a specific property has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I am building a login page and I get a similar problem but I found a solution with the next code:
I wrap the performSegueWithIdentifier with dispatch_async to get the main queue and I configured prepareForSegue to pass the data into a variables that I created in EventsVC file.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

    var login: Int = 0
    var clientId: String = ""
    var email: String = ""
    // I'll send the data in this variable
    var userData = [String : AnyObject]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    @IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        if emailTextField.text != "" && passwordTextField.text != "" {

            userLogin(emailTextField.text!, userPassword: passwordTextField.text!)

        } else {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Fields are required!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
            alert.addAction(action)
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
        }
    }

    func userLogin(email: String, userPassword: String) {

        let userUrl = "\(URL_BASE)\(URL_KEY)User/login"
        let url = NSURL(string: userUrl)!

        let parameters = [
            "email" : email,
            "password" : userPassword
        ]

        Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

            if let data = response.result.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                print("Response JSON: \(data)")

                self.userData = data

                if let isLogin = data["check"] as? Int {
                    self.login = isLogin
                }

                if let client = data["client_id"] as? String {
                    self.clientId = client
                }

                print(self.userData)

                if self.login == 1 {
                    // You need to wrap methods that call UI updates with dispatch_asynch to get the main queue
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueEventsVC", sender: self.userData)
                    })

                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Your credentials are invalid!", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(action)
                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true){}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "segueEventsVC" {
            if let eventsVC = segue.destinationViewController as? EventsVC {
                    eventsVC.userData = self.userData
            }
        }
    }
}
```